# Importing an incomplete dates from excel file as character

Tags: r, excel, date, import

I want to import my data from excel to R. In the excel file I have columns with NA values, incomplete and full dates i.e. it says 2022-05-00 in one cell and in another cell on that same column I have a date that says 2020-04-24 which is a full date. I have several columns with this specific issue.

However I believe I can get around this issue by importing all date columns as characters into R, but how do I do that? Meaning when I do import I want all my date columns to be character and not Date-format to avoid this issue.

When I try to import them as numeric that will produce NA values and when I try to import them as character some will turn into numeric values and the incompletes will keep their "normal" formate i.e. 2022-05-00 on that same column.

I am using Rstudios default import library "readxl" right now.

Comment: `readxl::read_excel` has a `col_types` argument to specify the column types.

Comment: No sorry that won't work. I already tried it. When I try to specify "text" as col_types, it turns all real dates as numeric values and all dates with double zeros are kept with the same format.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:
After importing from excel we could use `parse_date` function from
`parsedate` package: See `?parsedate`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(dates = c("2022-05-00", "2020-04-24"))

library(parsedate)
df %>% 
  mutate(dates = parse_date(dates))
  

 dates              
  <dttm>             
1 2022-01-05 00:00:00
2 2020-04-24 00:00:00
```

Comment: Maybe I should specify it further, I am sorry if I was unclear. When a date says 2022-05-00, it means some date in May 2022.

Comment: This is the problem. A date should have a, day a month and  a year. If day is zero no date will be printed in the classical way. We could change all 00 to 01 indicating the first day of this month when day is 0 ?

Comment: You could do `library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(dates = c("2022-05-00", "2020-04-24"))

df %>% 
  mutate(dates = str_replace(dates, '00', '01'))
`

Comment: That's the problem I guess, I can't do that because I need to have those double zeros on kept in place. That's why I was thinking if I could import the whole column as character that would solve it, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a specific format for imported variables, you can use the `col_types` option in `read_excel`. Say you have a file with a numeric ID variable you want to keep numeric, and three columns with dates, you can go with:

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("myfile.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric", "text", "text", "text"))
```

If you want to import *all* your variables as text, you can just use `col_types = "text"`, as it is recycled.

That said, if you want to use those variables as actual dates, you will still have the problem that incomplete dates will be set to missing or may be parsed incorrectly, if that's your problem you should post a specific question for that issue.

Comment: That's what I did, it did not work, it gave me the problem I described in my original post.

Comment: Can you post your data, the actual code you used, and the output you get? The most likely problem is that the date column is coded as date in Excel, so they are actually numbers and what you get is a text string containing that number.

Comment: It's an excelfile so I can't post it here. But I created a dummy data with 4 observations in a new excelfile with 1 column. The code I used was: `test <- read_excel("Dataset/test.xlsx", col_types = c("text"))`

In the excelfile it's posted like this:
`2021-02-14
2022-05-00
2019-12-23
2018-09-00`

Comment: When I try to use the `code test <- read_excel("Dataset/test.xlsx", col_types = c("text"))` the ones with true dates turn into numeric values and the ones with double zero turns into normal characters

Comment: Check the format of the columns in Excel, if it's date (I'm almost sure it is) change it to text, that should do the trick.

Comment: Already tried that as well. What happens is that it will do the exact same in Excel. All the true dates will turn into numeric values and all the double zeros will keep their format

Comment: What happens if you export the excel file into CSV format? Does excel change the content of the cell in that case?